# SFML centering delayed by one frame

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm making a game using C++ and SFML. Right now, I have a grid made of tiles, and entities that can occupy those tiles. One of those entities is the player and I want to center the camera on this entity. I have a `sf::RenderWindow` and a `sf::View` to do this:

```
 21     sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(width, height), "");
 22     sf::View main_camera;
 23 
 24     window.setFramerateLimit(60);
 25 
 26     main_camera.setSize(width, height);
 27     window.setView(main_camera);
```

Every frame, I center the camera on the player right before drawing the window:

```
 99         window.clear();
100 
101         player.move(movement_flag);
102         grid.draw_all(window);
103 
104         if(moused_over) moused_over->draw_contents(window);
105 
106         player.center_camera(main_camera);
107         gui.display(window, camera_offset);
108 #ifdef DEBUG
109         printf("Drawing window, centered at [%4f, %4f]\n", main_camera.getCenter().x, main_camera.getCenter().y);
110 #endif  
111         window.setView(main_camera);
112         window.display();
```

My issue is that whenever I move, there is one frame of difference, where the player is off center: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQOeS.jpg (it doesn't show every frame because I went from 60 in the recording to 25 in the gif, but you can still see it several times)

Here is the debug output:

```
...
Drawing window, centered at [350.000000, 140.000000]
Drawing sprite at   [ 350,  140]
Centering camera at [ 350,  140]
Drawing window, centered at [350.000000, 140.000000]
Drawing sprite at   [ 350,  140]
Centering camera at [ 350,  140]
Drawing window, centered at [350.000000, 140.000000]

Got a movement flag of 4
DOWN address: 0xedbbcbd0
Drawing sprite at   [ 350,  210]
Centering camera at [ 350,  210]
Drawing window, centered at [350.000000, 210.000000]
Drawing sprite at   [ 350,  210]
Centering camera at [ 350,  210]
Drawing window, centered at [350.000000, 210.000000]

...
```

When I give input, the movement flag text triggers and I move down. The camera is then centered on the new coordinates before the next frame is drawn to the screen.

I would think it's some issue with the camera not being centered until the next frame, but the debug output shows that there is no point where the window is drawn and the camera has not been centered on the latest player coordinates.

I have no idea what's causing this. I can share more code if necessary. Any help figuring the problem out is greatly appreciated.

## EDIT:

I solved the problem. I'm not sure why but moving the `player.move(movement_flag)` to after `grid.draw_all(window)` seemed to do the trick:

```
 99         window.clear();
100 
101         grid.draw_all(window);
102         
103         if(moused_over) moused_over->draw_contents(window);
104 
105         gui.display(window, camera_offset);
106 #ifdef DEBUG
107         printf("Drawing window, centered at [%4f, %4f]\n", main_camera.getCenter().x, main_camera.getCenter().y);
108 #endif  
109         
110         player.move(movement_flag);
111         player.center_camera(main_camera);
112         window.setView(main_camera);
113         window.display();
```

Comment: You should separate handling game logic and rendering:

move

    player.move(movement_flag);
    player.center_camera(main_camera);
    window.setView(main_camera);

out of (before) `window.clear(); ... window.display();`

Comment: @tntxtnt Thanks for the tip. When I get to multiple levels, I will redesign my logic.